# Identifying deleted posts and comments from a page in FB using API's

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In one of our requirement using fql we are collecting posts from fb page.
I have to identify `deleted posts` from the page to remove those post from our storage based on the fb data usage policy.

I tried to get deleted `post_id` using `is_hidden` but it is not showing deleted post_ids.
The only option i have is to keep a track of all `post and comment ids`.

Please let me know if their is any other way to get all the deleted posts and comment ids using some API's or any tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will not get deleted posts from the API/via FQL – _because_ they have been _deleted_.

Comment: Thanks Cbroe for the information. I know i cannot get it but is their any way of getting some kind of notification that a certain post and comment has been deleted from the page.

Comment: You could try with [realtime updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.1) – but I think those only notify you about changes on fields of existing objects, but not deletion either.